# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'ewma'

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

```
mte_exp_wighted_avg = pd.ewma(mte, halflife=12)
plt.plot(mte)
plt.plot(mte_exp_wighted_avg, color='red')
plt.xticks(fontsize = 25)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 25)
plt.xlabel('Years', fontsize = 25)
plt.ylabel('CO2 Emission', fontsize = 25)
plt.title('CO2 emission by coal power generation', fontsize = 25)
plt.show()
```

code is shown above, pandas are upgraded

error is shown below

Comment: here is the error message 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-f27904a04686> in <module>()
----> 1 mte_exp_wighted_avg = pd.ewma(mte, halflife=12)
      2 plt.plot(mte)
      3 plt.plot(mte_exp_wighted_avg, color='red')
      4 plt.xticks(fontsize = 25)
      5 plt.yticks(fontsize = 25)

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'ewma'

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO(StackOverflow)! You might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are able to edit your posts as well. So you might want to move your comment into the question.

Answer (score 4):

Pandas' *Exponential Moving Average function* (`ewma`) has been renamed to `ewm` as of Pandas 0.19. It's just a matter of changing some names:

```
mte_exp_wighted_avg = pd.ewm(mte, halflife=12)
plt.plot(mte)
plt.plot(mte_exp_wighted_avg, color='red')
plt.xticks(fontsize = 25)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 25)
plt.xlabel('Years', fontsize = 25)
plt.ylabel('CO2 Emission', fontsize = 25)
plt.title('CO2 emission by coal power generation', fontsize = 25)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

pd.ewma(mte, halflife=12) will not work anymore.
ewma has been changed to  ewm
mte_exp_wighted_avg = mte.ewm(halflife=12,min_periods=0,adjust=True,ignore_na=False).mean()

Comment: what is the mte package?